# HTML/CSS Video. embedding multiple video

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to have multiple videos on a HTML webpage? if so, how would this be accomplished in the neatest possible way.(LOL i am very new to HTML) I am only using html and css.

Comment: same question, you can get more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482536/i-have-multiple-html5-flowplayers-on-a-page-how-to-i-make-them-play-mutually-ex

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [mediaelementjs.com](http://mediaelementjs.com/) is a nice plugin if you are targeting for multiple devices and browsers.

Or simply put video tags like below

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: would i just put all the videos in separate div tags so that i could position them the way i liked?

Comment: You could use CSS to manage that. Or checkout above link mediaelementjs

Answer (score 0):

yes it can be done,there is plenty of examples..

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/32163/how-can-i-have-multiple-videos-on-a-page-with-only-playing-one-at-a-time/

http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/solutions/displaying-multiple-videos-single-page

Answer (score -1):

[HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5) is an new version of the language HTML, with new elements, attributes, and behaviors.

```
<video>
   <source type="video/mp4" src="PATH TO VIDEO 2">
   <source type="video/flv" src="PATH TO VIDEO 2">
   <source type="video/webm" src="PATH TO VIDEO 2">
</video>
```

Comment: would i just put all the videos in separate div tags so that i could position them the way i liked?

Comment: only one video will be visible..they are the quality formats of the video.For example you can see youtube vedio's in different quality.